# Removing orphan letters in a list with Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a python list:

```
list = ['clothing items s','shoes s','handbag d','fashion k']
```

I have used a for loop that removed words from the above list using another list.

The challenge I have been facing is the issue around plurals/singulars. This has left me with random orphan letters.

Do you know how to loop through the list items and identify single letters such as 's','d','k' (in the above example) and remove them? While in the example the orphan is at the end of the string, it is not always the case.

Here is my current loop:

```
new_new_keywords = []

#first we start looping over every keyword
for keyword in new_keywords2:

    # loop over every stop
    for stop in new_stops:
        # check if this stop is inside the current new_key
        if stop in keyword:
            # if it is, update the new key to remove the current stop
            keyword = keyword.replace(stop, '')
            #regex removes numbers at the end of the string in the list
            keyword = re.sub(" \d+", " ", keyword)
    #loop over the keyword over and over again until
    #remove every stop word

    # append the new stop-less keyword to the end of the array
    # even if there are no changes
    new_new_keywords.append(keyword)
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information on what you need filtered (for example 'a' is a perfectly valid word you might want to keep) but it's likely that a regular expression will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks SuperBiasedMan . 

So I am removing a singular word and am generally left with the leftover from the plurals. So it varies. 

I am trying to avoid regex mainly because I am not comfortable with it at this point in my development

Comment: You could possibly add a test when removing the word to see if actually removing the word will cause orphaned letters to be left behind. Can you edit your question to show the code for how you're removing the words?

Comment: let me expand on that. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rather old fashioned (and inefficient) approach which should work. This will preserve your original strings, apart from removing the unwanted characters:

```
test_list = ['clothing items s','shoes s','handbag d','fashion k', 'keep a', 'keep i', 'leave a alone remove k', 'keep ,  spacing b']

remove_list = "sdk"   # letters that need to be removed
newlist = []

for item in test_list:
    item += "_"     # append unused symbol to end of string

    for letter in remove_list:
        item = item.replace(" %s " % letter, "")
        item = item.replace(" %s_" % letter, "")

    newlist.append(item.rstrip("_"))

print newlist
```

It gives the following output:

```
['clothing items', 'shoes', 'handbag', 'fashion', 'keep a', 'keep i', 'leave a alone remove', 'keep ,  spacing b']
```

If at some point you choose to give regular expressions a go, then similar logic can be achieved using the following:

```
import re

test_list = ['clothing items s','shoes s','handbag d','fashion k', 'keep a', 'keep i', 'leave a alone remove k', 'keep ,  spacing b']

remove_list = "sdk"
newlist = [re.sub(" ([%s])( |$)" % remove_list, "", item) for item in test_list]

print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to decide what are invalid ending single letters preceded by a space, once the string length is > 1, the second last letter is a space and the last is in the rm set then slice the string to remove the chars, else just keep the string as is.:

```
lst = ['clothing items s','clothing s','shoes s','handbag d','fashion k']
rm = set((" bcdefghjklnpqrstuvwzy"))


print([ch[:-2] if all((len(ch) > 1,ch[-2].isspace(),ch[-1] in rm)) else ch 
      for ch in lst])
['clothing items', 'clothing', 'shoes', 'handbag', 'fashion']
```

You can reverse the logic with what letters that are valid.

```
lst = ['clothing items s','clothing s','shoes s','handbag d','fashion k']
st = set("ioa")

print([ch[:-2] if all((len(ch) > 1,ch[-2].isspace(),ch[-1] not in st)) else ch
       for ch in lst])
```

You might also want to call *str.lower* on the strings as `I` and `O` should be *capitalised* when used by themselves.

You can use rsplit again and a loop, you just have to decide if you want to keep only valid single letter words I,O,a but that would not mean your sentence was grammatically correct either:

```
lst = ['clothing items s', 'clothing s', 'shoes s', 'handbag d', 'fashion k']
rm = set("bcdefghjklnpqrstuvwzy")
out = []
for s in lst:
    spl = s.rsplit(None,1)
    if spl[-1] not in rm:
        out.append(s)
    else:
        out.append(s[:-2])

print(out)
```

Or using a regex:

```
lst = ['clothing items s', 'clothing s', 'shoes s', 'handbag d', 'fashion k']
import re

r = re.compile(r"\s[bcdefghjklnpqrstuvwzy]$")
print([r.sub("", ele) for ele in lst])
['clothing items', 'clothing', 'shoes', 'handbag', 'fashion']
```

Even considering what are possible one letter words then you would still need to see if the sentence was grammatically correct, for that you would need to use something like [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/howto/featgram.html), you could add a lowercase `i` and `o` to re or the set of letters to further filter your data but only you can decide what is relevant. If you want a robust solution and  the sentence to be grammatically correct then there is a lot more work than simply just removing all or certain single trailing letters at the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that. sometimes there are multiple words.

Comment: what possible letters/characters can appear?

Comment: I generally removing singulars, so the 'leftovers'. so generally 's' but there are other orphans that tend to vary by day and can not always be predicted.

Answer (score 0):

Take each string `s`, split it in words `w`, then reassemble `s` filtering out words with only 1 letter:

```
map(lambda s: ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if len(w) > 1), list)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That's a problem about how the problem is stated.

Comment: `a` is  a valid word so even with the original description this is wrong

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't want to polemicise, for sure your interpretation is correct, but the OP posted "*identify single letters*" and `a` is a single letter. Is up to the OP to provide an MCVE question.

Comment: The OP is obviously looking for letters at the end of the string specifically, I, a and O are legitimate words at the start, middle or end  so your approach could not be valid regardless. You also split every word which is redundant as only the last word/character in multiple word strings should be checked

Answer (score -1):

Straightforward solution - it deletes single letter words starting from last element:

```
def trim(s):
    parts = s.split()
    while parts:
        if len(parts[-1]) == 1:
            del parts[-1]
        else:
            break
    return ' '.join(parts)


assert trim('clothing items s') == 'clothing items'
assert trim('fashion a b c') == 'fashion'
assert trim('stack overflow') == 'stack overflow'
assert trim('have a nice day') == 'have a nice day'
assert trim('a b c') == ''
```